# Image Upload not working on a form

Tags: php, class, resize

So i have a form, that i use to regist users. And then i have a image field, using a resize class, to store the image on a folder, and save the name on the database. I have two problems:

The image is not being resized and place on the folder, and the code only stores the image name, not the extension, and it should store the extension too.

So here is my code:

```
try {

    $myValidation = new classes_ValidateForm ('registerUser', $_POST);
    $validationResult = $myValidation->getStatus();
    if (!is_array($validationResult)) {

    $arqName = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $arqTemp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
    $pasta = 'img/';

//extensao do arquivo enviado

    $extensaoTemp = explode('.',$arqName);

    $extensao = strtolower(end($extensaoTemp));

//nome do arquivo TimesTamp

    $nome = time(). '.' . $extensao;

    $upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $nome);

    if ($upload === true)

    {



          $ficheiro = $pasta.$nome; 

          $resizeObj = new resize($ficheiro); 

          $resizeObj -> resizeImage(1600, 1200, 'auto');

          $resizeObj -> saveImage("img/$nome", 100);

          $resizethumb = new resize($ficheiro); 

          $resizethumb -> resizeImage(200, 125, 'crop');

          $resizethumb -> saveImage("img/thumbnails/$nome", 100);

    }

    $myUser = new classes_User ($_POST, 'newUser');
        $myUserManager = new classes_UserManager($myControlPanel);

        $userResult = $myUserManager->addUser($myUser, $_POST['password'], $nome);

        echo $userResult;
        die();

}
}
```

And here is the function to add a user:

```
public function addUser($myUser, $password, $image) {

    if (!is_a ($myUser, 'classes_User')) {

        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid Object');
    }

    // 1 Get Username and email
    $username = $myUser->getUsername();
    $email = $myUser->getEmail();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";
    $myDb = $this->_controlPanel->getMyDb();
    $result = $myDb->performQuery($query);

    if ($result == "Query Error") {

        return ("ERROR ADDING USER");
    }

    elseif ($result->num_rows==1) {

        return (false);
    }

    else {

        $name = $myUser->getName();
        $encpassword = md5($password);
        $idtype = $myUser->getUserType();



        $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, password, id_type, image) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$email', '$encpassword', '$idtype', '$image')";

        $result = $myDb->performQuery($query);

        if($result != true) {

            return ("Error Adding User:Query");
        }

        else {

            echo "<h2> You have been registered. You will be redirected to the login page.</h2>";
            header( "Refresh:3; url=login.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Im using this resize class:

https://gist.github.com/leonelsr/3291939#file-resize-class-php

What am i doing wrong here? It stores the $nome in the database, but not with the extension of the photo as it is supposed too. And the image is not stored in the folder too.

Comment: make sure you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  in your Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should ***Use the SplFileInfo Class*** to obtain the files extension like this:

```
    <?php

        try {

            $myValidation       = new classes_ValidateForm ('registerUser', $_POST);
            $validationResult   = $myValidation->getStatus();

            if (!is_array($validationResult)) {
                $arqName        = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
                $arqTemp        = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
                $pasta          = 'img/';

                //extensao do arquivo enviado
                // TRY GETTING THE EXTENSION IN A SIMPLE FASHION...
                // SIMPLICITY, SOMETIMES, IS PREFERABLE
                //$extensaoTemp   = explode('.',$arqName);
                //$extensao       = strtolower(end($extensaoTemp));

                // SO WE GET THE FILE EXTENSION USING THE SplFileInfo CLASS LIKE SO:
                $info           = new SplFileInfo($flName);
                $extensao       = $info->getExtension();


                //nome do arquivo TimesTamp
                $nome           = time(). '.' . $extensao;


                // MAYBE CHECK FIRST THAT THE DIRECTORY EXIST BEFORE MOVING IT.
                // AND IF IT DOESN'T YOU MAY WANT TO CREATE IT LIKE SO:                 
                if(!is_dir($pasta)){
                    mkdir($pasta, 0777, true);
                }

                $upload         = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $nome);

                if ($upload === true) {
                    $ficheiro       = $pasta.$nome;
                    $resizeObj      = new resize($ficheiro);
                    $resizeObj      ->resizeImage(1600, 1200, 'auto');
                    $resizeObj      ->saveImage("img/$nome", 100);
                    $resizethumb    = new resize($ficheiro);
                    $resizethumb    ->resizeImage(200, 125, 'crop');
                    $resizethumb    -> saveImage("img/thumbnails/$nome", 100);
                }

                $myUser         = new classes_User ($_POST, 'newUser');
                $myUserManager  = new classes_UserManager($myControlPanel);
                $userResult     = $myUserManager->addUser($myUser, $_POST['password'], $nome);

                echo $userResult;
                die();

            }
        }catch(Exception $e){

        }
```